# ITextSharp Parsing HTML with Images in it: It parses correctly but wont show images

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am trying to generate a .pdf from html using the library ITextSharp. I am able to create the pdf with the html text converted to pdf text/paragraphs

**My Problem:** The pdf does not show my images(my **img** elements from the html). All my **img** html elements in my html dont get displayed in the pdf? Is it possible for ITextSharp to parse HTML & display images. I really hope so otherwise I am stuffed :(

I am linking to the correct directory where the images are(using IMG_BASURL) but they are just not showing

My code:

```
// mainContents variable is a string containing my HTML
var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 80, 100);
var output = new MemoryStream();
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
document.open();

Hashtable providers = new Hashtable();
providers.Add("img_baseurl","C:/users/xx/VisualStudio/Projects/myproject/");
var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(mainContents), null, providers);
foreach (var htmlElement in parsedHtmlElements)
   document.Add(htmlElement as IElement);

document.Close();
```

Answer (score 11):

Every time that I've encountered this the problem was that the image was too large for the canvas. More specifically, even a naked `IMG` tag internally will get wrapped in a `Chunk` that will get wrapped in a `Paragraph`, and I think that the image is overflowing the Paragraph but I'm not 100% sure.

The two easy fixes are to either enlarge the canvas or to specify image dimensions on the HTML `IMG` tag. The third more complex route would be to use an additional provider `IMG_PROVIDER`. To do this you need to implement the `IImageProvider` interface. Below is a very simple version of one

```
    public class ImageThing : IImageProvider {
        //Store a reference to the main document so that we can access the page size and margins
        private Document MainDoc;
        //Constructor
        public  ImageThing(Document doc) {
            this.MainDoc = doc;
        }
        Image IImageProvider.GetImage(string src, IDictionary<string, string> attrs, ChainedProperties chain, IDocListener doc) {
            //Prepend the src tag with our path. NOTE, when using HTMLWorker.IMG_PROVIDER, HTMLWorker.IMG_BASEURL gets ignored unless you choose to implement it on your own
            src = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\" + src;
            //Get the image. NOTE, this will attempt to download/copy the image, you'd really want to sanity check here
            Image img = Image.GetInstance(src);
            //Make sure we got something
            if (img == null) return null;
            //Determine the usable area of the canvas. NOTE, this doesn't take into account the current "cursor" position so this might create a new blank page just for the image
            float usableW = this.MainDoc.PageSize.Width - (this.MainDoc.LeftMargin + this.MainDoc.RightMargin);
            float usableH = this.MainDoc.PageSize.Height - (this.MainDoc.TopMargin + this.MainDoc.BottomMargin);
            //If the downloaded image is bigger than either width and/or height then shrink it
            if (img.Width > usableW || img.Height > usableH) {
                img.ScaleToFit(usableW, usableH);
            }
            //return our image
            return img;
        }
    }
```

To use this provider just add it to the provider collection like you did with `HTMLWorker.IMG_BASEURL`:

```
providers.Add(HTMLWorker.IMG_PROVIDER, new ImageThing(doc));
```

It should be noted that if you use `HTMLWorker.IMG_PROVIDER` that you are responsible for figuring out everything about the image. The code above assumes that all image paths need to be prepended with a constant string, you'll probably want to update this and check for `HTTP` at the start. Also, because we're saying that we want to completely handle the image processing pipeline the provider `HTMLWorker.IMG_BASEURL` is no longer needed.

The main code loop would now look something like this:

```
        string html = @"<img src=""Untitled-1.png"" />";
        string outputFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "HtmlTest.pdf");
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
            using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 80, 100)) {
                using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs)) {
                    doc.Open();
                    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(html)) {
                        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object> providers = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();
                        providers.Add(HTMLWorker.IMG_PROVIDER, new ImageThing(doc));

                        var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sr, null,  providers);
                        foreach (var htmlElement in parsedHtmlElements) {
                            doc.Add(htmlElement as IElement);
                        }
                    }
                    doc.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

One last thing, make sure to specify which version of iTextSharp you are targetting when posting here. The code above targets iTextSharp 5.1.2.0 but I think you might be using the 4.X series.

Comment: I'm trying to create and use a class that implements IImageProvider based on this code but it's not working and I believe it has something to do with this line:

providers.Add(HTMLWorker.IMG_PROVIDER, new ImageThing(doc));

I'm coding in C# and I'm not able to use the HTMLWorker.IMG_PROVIDER enumeration when I add to my hashtable.  Does it matter if this value is simply a string?  Also maybe I need to do something further from inside the loop to actually execute the GetImage code from the ImageProvider class.  I'm using itextsharp 4.1.6, in case that matters.

Comment: @Neitherman, please post a new question with what you tried and what didn't work, referencing this post if it makes sense.

Comment: Posted new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684040/imageprovider-not-working-in-html-to-pdf-conversion

Comment: `IImageProvider` is depracted since 5.5.2 (http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/html/simpleparser/ImageProvider.html)

Comment: `HTMLWorker` itself deprecated, not just that class.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and tried the following proposed solutions:
string replaced a tag, encode in base64 and embed the image to a .NET class library but none worked !
So I've come to the old fashioned solution: adding the logo manually with `doc.Add()`
Here's your code updated:

```
string html = @"<img src=""Untitled-1.png"" />";
        string outputFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "HtmlTest.pdf");
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
            using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 80, 100)) {
                using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs)) {
                    doc.Open();
                    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(html)) {
                        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object> providers = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();
                        providers.Add(HTMLWorker.IMG_PROVIDER, new ImageThing(doc));

                        var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sr, null,  providers);
                        foreach (var htmlElement in parsedHtmlElements) {
                            doc.Add(htmlElement as IElement);
                        }
// here's the magic
var logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/HTMLTemplate/logo.png"));
                logo.SetAbsolutePosition(440, 800);
                document.Add(logo);
// end
                    }
                    doc.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: To save someone time, you don't need the server.map path. You can use a file path if you aren't using a web app.

Answer (score -1):

```
string siteUrl = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/images/image/ticket/Ticket.jpg");
string HTML = "<table><tr><td><u>asdasdsadasdsa <img src='" + siteUrl + "' al='tt' /> </u></td></tr></table>";
```

Comment: It would be nice to know how or why this works, if it does... and I believe this would not work with the current version of iTextSharp as the <table> tag is not supported.

Comment: Just got this working and though @GuruRaja's initial comment won't work in the current version of iTextSharp. It will work, however, if you remove the <table>, <tr>, and <td> container tags AND use a URL as the image source (not a physical server path).